# Mod rewrite + hash tags

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

Does mod rewrite work together with hashtags? Maybe my code is crap, but this does not seem to work:

My site uses this hash tag: index.php/#p/about

It works fine using regular hashtags but i want it to work with mod rewrite so i tried with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php#p/$1 [nc]
```

My js:

```
$(window).hashchange(function(){      alert(location.hash);


}

$(window).hashchange();
```

The out put does not work when i try the mod rewrite for example:

site.com/about

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hashtags are only client-side, they aren't sent to the server, so you cannot rewrite to such an URL, but you can redirect to it with the `R` flag:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php#p/$1 [NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: N.B. The [`NE` (no escape)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) flag is important here, otherwise the hash will get URL escaped to `%23`.