# .htaccess correct format for RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a "JQueried" page using tabs - Tab A, Tab B etc the tabs hide/show content based on a link like this: `<a href="#tab1" title="Tab1 title">Tab 1</a>`  I am using jQuery Address Plugin v1.4
http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ to create new page titles and a new URL for each tab.  If you do not know the Address Plugin recreates the URL so the link #tab1 creates the URL page.html#tab1 but without a page refresh.  It also changes the page title but is there any way to create an RewriteRule so that `http://domain/page.html#tab1` can be called by say `http://domain/tab1.html` (where tab1,tab2 etc. have proper names not tab!)

Have tried but don't seem to get it to work. e.g.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule about.html /test.php#tab1 [NC]
```

suggestions please.  Thanks in advance - oh the htaccess will go in the actual root folder

Comment: I have just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606127/mod-rewrite-hash-tags so I guess can't be done

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I checked `\#`, it didn't work for me either.

How about redirecting to `test.php?hash=tab1`, and then:

```
if (isset($_GET["hash"]))
 header ( "Location: test.php#".$_GET["hash"] );
```

Comment: thanks but no joy have adjusted to this but still no joy Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about\.html$ test.php\#tab1

Comment: "Sorted" this is about SEO more than Rewrite so have reverted back to a ?var but kept the tabs, page refresh but dynamically change titles etc. e.g. var urlQuery = location.search; urlQuery = urlQuery.replace('?', ''); var split = urlQuery.split('='); jQuery(document).ready(function(){if(split[0]=='c'){ jQuery('#panels .panel').removeClass('active'); jQuery('#panels .panel:nth-child('+split[1]+')').addClass('active'); jQuery('#'+split[0]+''+split[1]).parent('li').addClass('active'); document.title = jQuery('#'+split[0]+''+split[1]).attr('title'); } }); unless anybody can think of better way

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment above - I have just found this stackoverflow.com/questions/8606127/mod-rewrite-hash-tags so I guess can't be done –